# Arm NEON and poly8_t and poly16_t

Tags: c++, c, arm, neon, intrinsics

I've been looking into neon optimisation with intrinsics recently and I have come across the poly8_t and poly16_t data types.  I'm then left wondering what on earth they are.

I've searched all across the net but so far have been unable to find ANY explanation of what they are.

Can anyone explain them to me?

***Edit***: Thanks for those answers but why, if it is just a different way of multiplying etc, does it have a totally different data type?

Comment: Used for polynomial multiplication I believe. Search for 'polynomial multiplication neon'

Comment: From https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/clang/+/release_29/test/Sema/neon-vector-types.c line: `typedef short poly16_t;`

Comment: @self: that doesn't say anything about what they are ...

Comment: I would check http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html and see how they are actually used - how they convert to assembly instructions.

Comment: Also see [Implementing GCM on ARMv8](http://conradoplg.cryptoland.net/files/2010/12/gcm14.pdf) by Gouvêa and López.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Left = regular multiplication, Right = carryless multiplication

```
        1 1 0 1                              1 1 0 1
     *  1 0 0 1                              1 0 0 1
   ------------        -->              --------------
     (1)1 1 0 1  <-- (1) is carry            1 1 0 1
      0 0 0 0                              0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0                              0 0 0 0
  1 1 0 1        +                     1 1 0 1         + GF(2) or XOR
  -------------                        ---------------
  1 1 1 0 1 0 1                        1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Each 1 or 0 in the diagonally descending matrix represents *partial product* of one source bit from the vector '1101' and one source bit from the other vector '1001'.

The applications of the right one are in CRC, (ECC) Error Correction Code calculations (Reed Solomon, BCH) and cryptography (elliptic curves, internals of AES).

Illustrating the connection to *polynomial* multiplication, the operation above can summarized as

```
 1101 == x^3 + x^2 + 0 + 1;
 1001 == x^3 + 0   + 0 + 1;
```

Regular polynomial multiplication being: p(x) * (x^3 + 1) == p(x)*x^3 + p(x) ==

```
 (x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^3 + 1) == x^6+x^5+x^3 + x^3+x^2+1 
                          == 1x^6 + 1x^5 + 0x^4 + 2x^3 + 1^x2 + 0x + 1
                          == "1102101"
```

In GF(2) each coefficient is simply calculated modulo 2, making ***1100101b***.

The datatype in GF looks just like uint8_t, uint16_t or perhaps upto 128_t in respect that the datatype for GF(2^8) holds 256 unique bitpatterns. However e.g. the bitpattern '00010001' e.g. has no traditional interpretation. (It's not 17 decimal, but perhaps 123th power of "unity" modulo some other polynomial.) Multiplying this number with the same "unity" modulo the generator polynomial g(x) leads to 124th power and so on. Then the properties (identities) of the finite fields have just interesting applications -- such that one can (remotely) easily calculate what 32-bit number to append to a file to make it's 32-bit CRC to match; or one can use the properties to *parallelize* crc calculation, or to implement bignum multiplication with Fourier-like transform in Finite fields (Number Theoretic Transform).

Comment: `poly8x16_t vmulq_p8 (poly8x16_t, poly8x16_t)` give *Form of expected instruction(s): vmul.p8 q0, q0, q0*.  If it is `vmul.p8`, does it mean GF(2^8), but your explanation is GF(2)?  Ie, there is no carry at the eighth bits, but there is in-between.  The GF(2) multiply is `XOR/EOR`.

Comment: GF(2) multiplication is AND operation; Addition in GF(2) and in it's extensions GF(2^n) is XOR. The polynomial multiplication uses XOR to sum up rows, when regular binary multiplication would use ADD. (in ADD there is a potential carry in between all bits). I haven't checked the docs, but I believe vmul.p8 would take just the 8 least significant bits of carryless product; and vmull.p8 would produce full product from p8*p8->p16.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking `vmull` and **GF(256)** as opposed to **GF(2^8)**.

Answer (score 6):

These types are used for carry-less multiplication. It is useful for cryptographic algorithms and CRC hash sums. Here are some white papers about applications (they explore x86 PCLMULQDQ instruction, but the same ideas apply to carry-less multiplication on ARM processors):

- [Intel Carry-Less Multiplication Instruction and its Usage for Computing the GCM Mode](http://download-software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/165685/clmul-wp-rev-2.01-2012-09-21.pdf)
- [Fast CRC Computation for Generic Polynomials Using PCLMULQDQ Instruction](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf)
- [Intel Polynomial Multiplication Instruction and its Usage for Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/polynomial-multiplication-instructions-paper.pdf)

Comment: Which instruction does carry-less multiplication on ARM?

Comment: ARM in this context must mean Cortex A7 or A8 processors, which include the NEON extension. I think it's `VMUL.P8`

Comment: @auselen In ARMv7 the instruction is called `VMULL.P8` (`8-bit x 8-bit -> 16-bit`). In ARMv8 the instruction is called `PMUL`/`PMULL`/`PMULL2`. ARMv8 with cryptography extensions supports `64-bit x 64-bit -> 128-bit` carry-less multiplication in addition to the ARMv7 variant.

Answer (score 2):

You did not describe PMUL vs PMULL.

As I understand it (probably incorrectly) each per element
PMUL works on two 8 bit source elements and generates one 
8-bit result element.

Each per element PMUL generates 8 partial products and
each PP are shifted respectively before XORed. So from
the lsb of the first PP to the msb of the last PP.
There seem to be 15-bits of result. PMUL can only store 
an 8-bit result.

Are the most significant 7-bits of 15-bit result discarded?

Answer (score 1):

As a reference, this is from [Cortex-A Series Programmer’s Guide (v4)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013d/index.html) chapter 7.2.2:

> Polynomial arithmetic is useful when implementing certain cryptography
>   or data integrity algorithms.
>
> Adding two polynomials over {0,1} is the same as a bitwise exclusive
>   OR. Polynomial additional results in different values to a
>   conventional addition.
>
> Multiplying two polynomials over {0,1} involves first determining the
>   partial products as done in conventional multiply, then the partial
>   products are exclusive ORed instead of being added conventionally.
>   Polynomial multiplication results in different values to conventional
>   multiplication because it requires polynomial addition of the partial
>   products.